# Changing individual bar color in a bar graph without for loop

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I want to change individual bar color in a bar graph in MATLAB. I surely can do it using for loop but is it possible to do it without using for loop, something like vector operation.

This is the minimal example using for loop

```matlab
distr = [11,12,34,45,9];
totalkeys = numel(distr);
color = parula(totalkeys);
hold on;
for i = 1:totalkeys
bb= bar(i-1, distr(i), 'facecolor', color(i,:),'BarWidth', 1);
end
hold off;
xlim([0 totalkeys-1]);
```

BTW I am using MATLAB R2016a.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to avoid the for loop? Is this code too slow? I doubt a for loop would slow down any graphics rendering. Before optimizing based on “loops are slow” (which is no longer true), profile your code to identify the bottleneck, then optimize that bit.

Comment: If you change `bb = bar(...)` to `bb(i) = bar(...)`, then after all your code try  `bb(3).FaceColor = [1 0 0];` though if I'm honest I'm not sure why you repeatedly call `bar`. But I tested this and it worked in R2017a.

Comment: Documentation examples for [`bar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) include how to do this setting `'FaceColor'` property to `'flat'` the adjusting the color of the i-th bar via `CData(i,:) = [r g b]`.  But I don't think that works for your version.  Does `bb.CData` exist in your version?

Comment: @CrisLuengo , I am using this bar graph in another for loop which runs around 1000 times, so having this for loop is slowing down the whole process.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan No CData doesn't exist for MATLAB R2016a. I think it came after R2017b

Answer (score 3):

From **R2017b onwards** 
(thanks to [@SecretAgentMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8239061/secretagentman) for noting that this is version-specific), the [`bar`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) object has a `CData` property to specify the color of each bar. However, you also need to change the `FaceColor` property to make this work:

> Set the `FaceColor` property of the `Bar` object to `'flat'` so that the chart uses the colors defined in the `CData` property.

```
distr = [11,12,34,45,9];
color = parula(numel(distr));
bar(distr,'BarWidth', 1 ,'FaceColor', 'flat', 'CData',color);
```

[image]

Comment: What version did you test that with? Does not work in R2017a due to no CData property on Bar class.  (+1 anyway, this answer is what my comment above was referring to and is the best way for **future visitors**)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Oh. I hadn't seen your second comment in the question. I'm using R2017b. So now we know this is the first version where it works

Comment: @SecretAgentMan 
So I need to use R2017b version. Is there anyway to do it with my current version

Comment: I can’t think of any, other than the loop, sorry